# Easiest way to store console output on non-developer iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, console

I am making a game that has its own level editor. The editor simply outputs code to the console which I can then copy from the console and paste into my game. Stuff like terrain points, asset locations etc. Simple text basically.

I will be issuing the app to a colleague (who is not technical) and need to save the level data that the colleague will create. What is the easiest way for me to store this level information on his device for me to access later (assuming he doesn't have a developer account etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruct them to download and install the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) (not the Configurator), it's available for both Windows and MacOS X. It shows you the iOS console output once the device is plugged in, you can copy-paste from it all you want.

Comment: Is iPhone Configuration Utility discontinued? I can not find it anywhere on the Apple's site. Is there an alternative for Windows?